# this is undefined in extended class

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have these 3 files:

bar.js

```
class Bar {
    test(p) {
        console.log(p);
    }
}

module.exports = Bar;
```

baz.js

```
const Bar = require('./bar');

class Baz extends Bar {
    test2(p) {
        this.test(p);
    }
}

module.exports = Baz;
```

foo.js

```
const Baz = require('./baz');
const { test2 } = new Baz();

test2('test');
```

When I passed `'test'` to `new Baz.test2()`, I expected it to pass it to it's superclass (`this.test(p)`) where it should log `'test'`. However, it threw the error:

```
        this.test(p);
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is `this` undefined, I thought it should reference the class itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Class/instance methods are not auto-bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test2` is used apart from it's original context (`Bar` instance) and should be bound to proper `this`.

It's impossible to say from the name if it's expected to be a callback by design. In case it is, it can be bound in constructor:

```
class Bar {
    constructor () {
        this.test = this.test.bind(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Otherwise it can be bound in-place:

```
const test2 = new Baz().test2.bind(this);

test2('test');
```

Or just not be used separately from the context:

```
const baz = new Baz()

baz.test2('test');
```